# How to handle customized so in C++ when deploying production?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I know there are many methods to let the executed file load the customized so. such as coping the so to /lib or /usr/lib , export ld_library_path, or modify ld.so.conf.

what's the best or common method to hand the customized so for executed file to load it when deploying production app?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to spilit file on lib folder??

In my case, I made folder and put on files on my folder.

And I set directories like that..

C/C+ --> Additional directory..

I did.

**"$(ProjectDir)..\Common\Button_src";"$(ProjectDir)..\lib\KLib\";**

Sorry ,, My answer is helpful to your question.

Comment: my meaning is which is the best method for executed file to load customized so? not in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way (used e.g. by OpenGL apps or Intel MKL library) is to locate the library that should be used at program startup, `dlopen` it and extract all necessary symbols via `dlsym`.